# Size of the circles in \draw[*-o] in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to change the size of the circles when using \draw[*-o] in tikzpicture? There are a little to big for my taste.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Circle` arrow tip from the `arrows.meta` library instead; the `length` key allows you to control the size:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[*-o]
  (0,0)  --  (4,0);
\draw[Circle-{Circle[open]}]
  (0,-1)  --  (4,-1);
\draw[{Circle[length=2pt]}-{Circle[open,length=2pt]}]
  (0,-2)  --  (4,-2);
\draw[{Circle[length=10pt]}-{Circle[open,length=10pt]}]
  (0,-3)  --  (4,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}        

\end{document}
```

Comment: It does not TEX on my computer.  It can't find file \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}.  I am using TeXShop Version 3.52.

Comment: @PiotrMikusinski You need a recent version of PGF/TikZ. (Version 3.0). Update your LaTeX system. (TeXshop is just an editor, not your LaTeX system; what you need to update is your LaTeX installation).